# Female USB to male PS/2 MINI DIN 6 adapter

Tags: usb, connector, adapter

I need an extension cable with male USB to PS/2 MINI DIN 6 connector. I have something like [this adapter](http://cgi.ebay.com/New-USB-female-PS-2-PS2-male-adapter-TVCS-199-Black-/280699125282?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item415af8be22):

[image: adapter photo]

However it does not fit in my Aten KVM switch correctly (the reduction is wider than standard PS2 connector) and I do not want to buy another switch or mouse. I'm thinking about creating an adapter from an old keyboard cable plus a male USB connector - in fact the same as the adapter on the picture, but with about 20cm of cable. However, I am not sure whether the mentioned adapter is passive or whether there is some integrated circuit to do the conversion.

I could also use a [PS2 extension cord](http://cgi.ebay.com/PS-2-MINI-DIN-6-M-F-EXTENSION-CABLE-KEYBOARD-MOUSE-/250782638727?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item3a63cf6287), but it's not an optimal solution. Has anyone got any experience in this area? I don't want to disassemble the reduction just to find out what is inside!

Comment: You could get the ps2 extension cord and hack it so it's smaller. Then it's just like an extension to your adaptor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a passive adaptor, usually, though there's active adaptors. Whole thing is encased in plastic internally, so you might be able to get away with hacking away the outer casing. I've never seen a extension cord of the sort you're talking about - you will want to check the maximum distance.

Also, why a *male* connector? you are looking at a female connector there.

Comment: As I know, the PS2 connector on the adapter is male while the USB one is female. The female PS2 is on the motherboard.

Comment: wouldn't you basically want a version of what you have there with a 'skinny' male PS/2 and female USB on the other end?

Comment: yes, you are right. In fact, standard PS/2 connector fits ok, while the adapter is a little bit "fat" and presses the other plugged connectors (probably because of the female usb connector) so I am afraid of damaging the input connectors of the KVM switch. This is the only reason, why I wanted to solve this.